# defrecord argument filtrering

Tags: clojure, record

Let's say I've defined a record like this:

```
(defrecord MyRecord [x y z])
```

And I construct it like this:

```
(def test (map->MyRecord {:x "1" :y "2" :z "3" :w "ikk"}))
```

I can do like this:

```
(:w test) ; Returns "ikk"
```

1. Why is `:w` retained? I'm thinking that since I've created a record that takes `x`, `y` and `z` these are the only "keys" that should be present.
2. Is there a good way to exclude keys that are not present as arguments in the `record` declaration without using `select-keys`?

For example:

```
(defrecord MyRecord1 [x y z])
(defrecord MyRecord2 [x y w])
(defprotocol MyProtocol
  (do-stuff [data]))

(extend-protocol MyProtocol
  MyRecord1
  (do-stuff [data]
    (let [data (select-keys data [:x :y :z])] ; (S1)
      ...))

  MyRecord2
  (do-stuff [data]
    (let [data (select-keys data [:x :y :w])] ; (S2)
      ...)))
```

I want to avoid doing `select-keys` (S1, S2) manually for each record when I use `MyProtocol` when records are constructed using `map->` with additional data (that I don't care about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clojure records implement [IPersistentMap](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IPersistentMap.java) (as well as [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for Java interop), and behaves like a normal map - this means that you can use them wherever and in the same way you would use maps. You can look at a record as a typed map - it's a map, but you can easily do dispatch using multimethods and protocols.

This makes it very easy to start representing your data using plain maps, and then advance to a record when you need the type.

As maps, records support additional keys, but they are treated differently. With your example, `(.x test)` works, but `(.w test)` does not, since only the predefined keys become fields in the implementing Java class.

To avoid extra keys, just make your own constructor:

```
(defn limiting-map->MyRecord
  [m]
  (map->MyRecord
   (select-keys m [:x :y :z])))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature of `defrecord`.  See: http://clojure.org/datatypes Section `deftype and defrecord`:

> defrecord provides a complete implementation of a persistent map, including:
>
> - ...
> - **extensible fields (you can assoc keys not supplied with the defrecord definition)**

Via Reflection you can see, that your x,y,z params are regular attributes of the object:

```
user=> (>pprint (.? (map->MyRecord {:w 4})))
(#[__extmap :: (user.MyRecord) | java.lang.Object]
 ;...
 #[x :: (user.MyRecord) | java.lang.Object]
 #[y :: (user.MyRecord) | java.lang.Object]
 #[z :: (user.MyRecord) | java.lang.Object])
```

And the additional values are stored in that `__extmap`:

```
 user=> (.-__extmap (map->MyRecord {:w 4}))
 {:w 4}
```

This means, that there is nothing left for you other than watch out on the places you want to deal with your record as a Map, since new keys can be added at any time:

```
user=> (let [r (->MyRecord 1 2 3) r (assoc r :w 4)] (keys r))
(:x :y :z :w)
```

So if you find yourself repeating code like `(select-keys myr [:x :y :z])` then extract that as a helper fn.

Adding things like your own c'tors is always a good idea (e.g. if you want to have `0` for missing keys instead of `nil` e.g.), but this only protects you from yourself and the users following your example.